# Strange thing in Laravel where on dd() it's ok, without it's 'not an object'?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Code:

```
    @foreach($room->students as $student)
         <li>
         {{ $student->student->first_name }}
         <a href="{{ route('student.show', $student) }}">{!! "{$student->student} {$student->last_name}" !!}</a>
        </li>
   @endforeach
```

This is a relation the `$student`

```
public function student()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Student::class);
    }
```

`$student` is actually here an `room_student` model. And this model `belongsTo` `student`.

The problem is?

The `$student->student->first_name` produces this error:

[image]

However this should work, because `$student->student` gives `Student` object as well because of relation (I gave code too).

So changing this line `{{ $student->student->first_name }}` to `{{ dd($student->student) }}` works good and produces this result:

[image]

And even better, look what we will get from this `{{ dd($student->student->first_name) }}`

[image]

Oh, it's great yeah? It works?

Nope, because once I take off the `dd()` function to it look like this: `{{ $student->student->first_name }}`...

[image]

Oh, again. Hello darkness my old friend...

So what is happening here? Why? Why with `dd()` works perfectly? Without doesn't? What is going on?

---

`die(var_dump())` on this

[image]

This is object. 100%. What is going on? Possible framework bug?

Comment: I think an object handler like `get_properties`, or a `__debugInfo()` magic method modifies your objects in some way and accidentally causes it to work when debugging but not work while not. But I have no idea what exactly causes your problem. Maybe you can narrow it down if you `serialize()` and `json_encode()` your object instead of `dd()`, and check how your program behaves then. Both function will not invoke the debug handlers/methods, but will invoke get handlers. Sadly both methods could cause magic of their own. [Here](https://3v4l.org/AHVM7) is a short reproducer of a sw similar issue.

Comment: dd() is executed during the first iteration of the foreach loop. It just means that the first item in the list is a Student object. Apparently somewhere later in the list you have an incorrect value. Check for the class of the variable and dd() only when it's not a Student.

Comment: That's a much simpler explanation than mine, and it fits the problem. Occam's razor ...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to put if condition before

```
@if(isset($student->student->first_name)
     $student->student->first_name
@endif
```

when you put dd($student->student) in your code, it was the first record in your loop and you got this error within your loop on one of the elements in the object, because of you don't have student relationship attached with one of your element in the loop.

that's why you need to attach if condition as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue like this before and i used multidimensional array to pass back the data. So in this case you might have to use this, it is very strange indeed. Hope this helps.

```
$student->student['0']['first_name'];
```